# .Net Core 3.1 Connected services to webservice causes fault

Tags: web-services, wcf, .net-core

I want to connect to https://wsiinst.uni-login.dk/wsiinst-v4/ws?WSDL.

This works fine in normal .NET 4.7.

But in .NET Core 3.1, the channel is Fault, when creating the Client..
My steps..

1. create .NEt Core console App
2. Add Connected service (Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider) , call it "ServiceRef"
3. Add this code to program.cs (main)

   `var client= new ServiceRef.WsiInstPortTypeClient();`
4. The client is created, but state is Faulted

Perhaps web service uses something, not supported yet in core ?

Anyone have an idea or canb point me in a direction ? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same, when you add connected reference you click in other references, that you will get the service endpoint and you have to put the URI. you click GO and will get the service avaliable. If this isn't working that's mean you have a problem in the serverside. Did you bind your port correctly??

check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-http

after you initalize the serviveref did you open the connection?

```
var client = new ServiceRef.WsiInstPortTypeClient();
await client.OpenAsync();
var getanobject = await client.MyobjectAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks alot m8... :-)
Totally overlooked the OpenAsync, since it was not needed using regular .NET..

Comment: glad I have been help to you.